# Why my Socket.io connection doesn't work?

Tags: angular, express, socket.io

Hi I'm learning how to use Socket.io, so now I can connect and disconnect users succesfully from my server, but my frontend doesn't receives the emit message send by the server, Im using Angular, and NodeJS(ExpressJS) so my server is configured this way:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

    io.on('connect',(socket)=>{
        console.log("conected: ");

        app.use('/user', userRoutes)

        socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
            console.log("disconected")
        })
    })

    http.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log("Server On");
    })
```

as you can see, a call my user routes in the io connection, and this one calls my `userController` as an end point, so I want to do `emit` in the `userController` and is like this:

```
async function changeStatus(req, res) { 
//amazing things with database
io.emit('changeStatus'()=>{console.log("send..")});
res.status(201).json({
            message: "Status updated :)"
        })
}
```

This means that everything that someone do on my controller it emits a message called `statusChanged`, and my frontend makes the rest like this:

```
export class SocketService {

private socket: any

constructor() {

this.socket = io('localhost:3000',{ transports : ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket' ] });

this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Conectado al servidor Socket.IO: ');
});

this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('Desconectado del servidor Socket.IO');
});

this.socket.on('changeStatus',()=>{
  console.log("reibido..")
})
```

}

This is my service and is called in my module constructor, and it works, connected and disconnected. To try this Im using post man to make a change in the database, and in fact as you can see in my server code, when i do an emit, it prints a message, and it prints every time I do a post man change,this means that every user that could be listening the server, should be receiving the message but angular doesn't and I don't now why .

At first the problem was the url, then the nicknames of the receiving message but for this I don't really know. Thank you if you can help me.!

Comment: You should pass a URL to socket.io, not just a host.  So, change to `this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000',{ transports : ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket' ] });`.  FYI, I can't think of any reason why you want to enable `flashsocket` at all, so remove it from the array.  flash is obsolete and full of security issues.

Comment: FYI, you can listen for the `error` event on your client socket.io and also look at the client console and see if you can see errors like this there to tell you more about what's happening.

Comment: Also, this looks wrong `io.emit('changeStatus'()=>{console.log("send..")});` on the server.  You are missing a comma after the event name.  Change to this: `io.emit('changeStatus', ()=>{console.log("send..")});`